# How to do Multiple OAuth2 Authentication in Browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, google-oauth

## **Problem**

I need OAuth2 Tokens for the user accessing the browser from multiple OAuth serves in order to have access tokens for accessing multiple resources.

The OAuth authentication process triggers when the user clicks a single button. Let's call it Login.

Well not exactly what we are doing picture getting the user simultaneously authenticating using Google and Azure AD, so tokens for each can be obtained. (*Having to manage individual credentials for each is an accepted pain point.*)

The problem though is how to code up the JavaScript to trigger and manage authenticating with each where they both use callbacks and browser redirects. And they both must simply reload the users existing page storing the JWT of both in hidden form fields. *(Using Session Storage is acceptable and happens anyway yet it must be retained between redirects.)*

### **Restrictions**

- Changing the basic requirements is not possible
- Adding new pages or radically changing the web application layout and pages is not possible
- Using vanilla JavaScript web app that is not SPA. Each page can be semi-SPA yet ultimately passes JWT back to server for use and gets another page for additional user interaction with the resource data fetched by server.
- No normal sever side coding possible. A special purpose engine is doing workflow orchestration and has limited low level coding capabilities.

### **Possible Solutions**

- Using hidden iframes may be possible if carefully managed and invisible to user
- Synchronise authentication where one OAuth process completes before the other starts

#### *Attempted*

- Using chained Promises, yet things get lost during the redirects, race conditions happen, and confusion breaks out.
- To use change state events of hidden form fields to orchestrate synchronises authentication, i.e. when one completes setting form field to obtained token that other starts

## ***Seeking***

- Some suggestions on how to solve the problem. Please indicate if your idea is something you've done or seen and know works, or something you think might work; I am grateful for both:-)
- Hints at things that will not work and should be avoided.

Comment: Have decided that given the restrictions it may not be possible to do this in seamless way and need instead to find a way to separate the authentication to distinct pages and change workflow a little to make this possible. 
Would still welcome any ideas on how to have multiple OAuth work well on single page when it loads.

Comment: Above decision to separate into distinct pages had to be abandoned as; a) new pages could not be introduced, b) subsequent existing pages all use dynamic URI with task process identifier query parameter and AzureAD cannot use wildcards for accepting RedirectURI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the browser session state to orchestrate first authenticating with one provider and then after that finished doing the other.

The basic issue was to ensure that each time it reloaded the page after a redirect containing the authentication code the correct authentication provider would pick up the code and complete the operation fetching the token. The session state was used to store an indicator as each completed.
As they both used callbacks it was necessary to chain callbacks which was done by using promises.